# Checkout Not Working on Windows 8 Mobile

Tags: checkout, mobile

I'm running Magento 1.702 with Ultimo theme.

Recently a customer told me he couldn't progress past entering his billing details on a Windows 8 mobile phone.

Note: I have combined steps 1 and 2 of the One Page Checkout, so billing details is presented as the first step - logging in or registering functionaility is now combined with the billing address form via [Skip Checkout Step 1 plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/skip-checkout-step-1.html).

At first, I assumed the above plugin was the problem, but I found someone else having the same issue in comments under the Ultimo theme on ThemeForest:

> One page checkout doesnt work on a mobile device. I am using Windows Phone 8 and the checkout doesnt advance further after I select Checkout as Guest.

To which the theme's developer replied:

> Checkout is Magento’s core functionality not related to the theme, the checkout process wasn’t modified in our theme (checkout was only styled with CSS), so if you see an error this is not from the theme.

This seems to rule out the theme being the problem, and the Skip Checkout Step 1 plugin, as the author of the above comment refers to the default checkout behaviour not working in a windows 8 mobile. I can also confirm this behaviour existed before I installed the plugin, as (according to google analytics) windows 8 phones have generated zero income since the site launched.

My questions:

1. Has anyone else noticed this behaviour? (Might be worth checking your own analytics data, or perhaps you have a windows8 phone and have trouble checking out on other magento-based sites?)
2. Does anyone know what might be causing the issue? Does the Windows 8 mobile browser handle javascript differently to desktop Internet Explorer?
3. Where is the cart javascript stored by default? In my case, `billing.save()` isn't working, but I would assume all `.save()` functions aren't working (as confirmed by the comment quoted above) - If I'm going to fix this, I assume this is the file that needs checking and editing?

Comment: For anyone here to be able to help you, you'll need to post the actual JS error blocking the checkout.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site? Have you turned off the specific extension and attempted to checkout using the scenario above?

Comment: davidalger - I have no idea what the JS error is as I don't have a windows 8 phone. Hence Question 1 above. Question 2 is more of a general question about how win8 mobile handles JS and question 3 is asking for the checkout JS file's location.

Comment: kab8609 - The problem was there before I installed the extension, as confirmed by previous analytics data. I mentioned it because I wanted to point out that it was the first step in the checkout, not necessarily the billing step, that was causing the problem.

Comment: @john Step one would be to either buy a windows phone or find someone willing to let you borrow theirs for testing for a bit. Even if you think you had a solution, you'd be blindly deploying an untested fix and it would still be impossible for you to know if it actually works or not. Another thing to consider is that windows mobile has less than 4% market share, so a simple lack of sales here doesn't neccesarily mean there is a problem.

Comment: Here is a windows phone emulator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx I would check to see if you can reproduce the error using the emulator.

Comment: @kab8609 Learned something today...MS has an emulator for their mobile platform. Hope it's faster than the android emulator! :)

Comment: I'm still looking into this problem. Turns out the latest internet explorer's debug tools let you view it as though you were using a windows phone. Not sure how accurate it is though. I'll report back when I know more, but at the moment it's looking like it could be a problem with a media query for small screens in the Ultimo theme's CSS. Thank you both for your help so far!

Comment: I have learned this isn't a CSS problem. The customer sent me some more info about the situation - said he filled in his details and then clicking the "Continue" button did nothing.

@davidalger - I confirmed the problem via analytics data for all windows phones since July after the customer told me about his problem. Other phones with smaller market shares have been able to place orders. Also see comment in original question copied from ThemeForest - someone else has confirmed it doesn't work.

Comment: @kab8609 - looks like I will have to give the emulator a go. Already knew about it, but was trying to avoid it. FYI, it can be used for free by downloading Visual Studio Express.

Comment: Ok, the emulator required Win 8 pro, which I do not have access to. If anyone would care to investigate the problem further, the URL in question is http://www.coffeesh0p.com although it's probably NSFW. Depends how liberal your boss is!

In the mean time, I shall try and gather more data and ask the theme's developers if they can check it out. I may also ask for help on the Windows 8 Phone stackexchange site. Perhaps at least someone over there can tell me exactly what's wrong so I can go about fixing it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party theme